# C# Nested If Statements whilst reading XML

Tags: c#, if-statement, nested-loops

I am reading a XML Weather document which is in the format of below -

```
<Rep D="ENE" F="1" G="9" H="81" Pp="9" S="7" T="3" V="VG" W="7" U="0">0</Rep> // 00:00
<Rep D="NE" F="0" G="9" H="86" Pp="1" S="4" T="3" V="VG" W="2" U="0">180</Rep> //03:00
<Rep D="NNE" F="0" G="9" H="87" Pp="4" S="4" T="2" V="GO" W="7" U="0">360</Rep> //06:00
<Rep D="NNE" F="2" G="7" H="81" Pp="8" S="4" T="4" V="VG" W="7" U="1">540</Rep> //09:00
<Rep D="NNE" F="5" G="7" H="72" Pp="4" S="2" T="6" V="VG" W="7" U="2">720</Rep> //12:00
<Rep D="N" F="6" G="7" H="69" Pp="4" S="2" T="7" V="VG" W="7" U="1">900</Rep> //15:00
<Rep D="NW" F="5" G="4" H="77" Pp="5" S="2" T="6" V="VG" W="7" U="1">1080</Rep> //18:00
<Rep D="N" F="2" G="9" H="88" Pp="8" S="4" T="4" V="VG" W="8" U="0">1260</Rep> //21:00
```

The  text value of the Rep element is related to the time in minutes.

To ensure I am reading the correct element am using an if statement I am storing the innerText of the Rep element as a variable then working out how many mins have been and comparing this value to the innerText to see which line I should be reading

```
   string RepValueZero = elemList[0].InnerText;
   string RepValueZero = elemList[0].InnerText;

    //Get the Number of Minutes in the day to calculate which row to read
    double mins = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes;

    if (mins > Convert.ToInt32(RepValueZero) && mins < Convert.ToInt32(RepValueOne))
    {
        //Get Temp and Weather Value From Row [0]
        string strTemp = elemList[0].Attributes["T"].Value;
        string strWeatherType = elemList[0].Attributes["W"].Value;
    }
```

... and so on.

After getting the values of 'W' - which is the weather type I then want to display a image. (But there are 30 possible values for 'W') How can i achieve this without having a nested if statement of 30 branches within each initial if statement (above)

```
if(W = 1)
{
  image1.ImageUrl = "w1.jpg";
}
if(W = 2)
{
  image1.ImageUrl = "w2.jpg";
}
...
...
if(W = 30)
{
  image1.ImageUrl = "w3.jpg";
}
```

Like below

```
       string RepValueZero = elemList[0].InnerText;
       string RepValueZero = elemList[0].InnerText;

        //Get the Number of Minutes in the day to calculate which row to read
        double mins = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes;

        if (mins > Convert.ToInt32(RepValueZero) && mins < Convert.ToInt32(RepValueOne))
        {
            //Get Temp and Weather Value From Row [0]
            string T = elemList[0].Attributes["T"].Value;
            string W = elemList[0].Attributes["W"].Value;

            if(W = 1)
            {
              image1.ImageUrl = "w1.jpg";
            }
            if(W = 2)
            {
              image1.ImageUrl = "w2.jpg";
            }
            ...
            ...
            if(W = 30)
            {
              image1.ImageUrl = "w3.jpg";
            }
        }
```

Comment: If your question is about working code then please show something that is an [MCVE] and clearly state the problem you have. At the moment your question is not clear.

Comment: Hopefully that will make it a little bit clearer - so I am writing everything to the page at the moment just so I can test to ensure I am reading the correct tag based on the innerText of the tag and the current time. I have left out all of the seven if statement and just used one if and else. Thanks

Comment: If the `ImageUrl` is based on the value of `W` then you could just build your URL using `W` and eliminate the need for `if`s. Otherwise I would use a `switch` statement.

Comment: OK - I have built the URL using image1.ImageURL = "w" + W + ".jpg"; which is great, but if I wanted to use the text value of the W i.e. 0 = Cloudy, 1 = Sunny, 2 = Thunder etc. Could you provide an example of the switch inside the if statement? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could replace this:

```
        if(W = 1)
        {
          image1.ImageUrl = "w1.jpg";
        }
        if(W = 2)
        {
          image1.ImageUrl = "w2.jpg";
        }
        ...
```

with this:

```
image1.ImageUrl = "w" + W + ".jpg";
```

Alternatively if you have a different image for each number, you can do something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> jpgsById = new Dictionary<int, string> ();
jpgsById[1] = "w1.jpg";
jpgsById[2] = "w2.jpg";
image1.ImageUrl = jpgsById[1];
```

Comment: Great - building the URL like you have described has worked for the image URL. I am not sure how I would get the Dictionary to work (I haven't used this before). If I wanted to use the description of W how could i incorporate this into my code i.e. 0 = Sunny, 1 = Cloudy, 2 = Partly Cloudy etc. Thanks

Comment: For the description, lookup enums.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 30 classes that inherit from Weather class, and have a WeatherFactory pattern that returns the specific WeatherSubclass depending on the string parameter.

```
abstract class Weather
{
 public string ImageUrl{get;set;};
}

class MildWeather : Weather
{
   public MildWeather()
  {
      ImageUrl = "your specific image for MildWeather";
  } 
}
```

and have in your code something like this

```
string T = elemList[0].Attributes["T"].Value;
string W = elemList[0].Attributes["W"].Value;
var weather = WeatherFactory.Create(W);

image1.ImageUrl = weather.ImageUrl;
```

So in case you want to add another Subclass because in your xml appears another value of W, just you need to do is inherit from Weather class and specify the image for that type, and your model will be extensible for those changes. You will not need to add an extra if.